Find $\angle CDE$
Let $ABC$ an equilateral triangle and $D$ inside the triangle such that $\angle ABD=20^{\circ} , \angle ACD=30^{\circ} $. Let $E$ on $BC$ such that $DE=BC$.
Find $\angle CDE$.
This is my picture:

I denote $\angle CDE=x$. I consider $F$ s.t. $ACFD$ paralelogram. Then $DCFB$ is an isoscel trapezoid. But I am stuck.

Please write an INFORMATIVE title.

may i know name of book from where this question is ?

I am trying to give a synthetic solution based on the symmetry of a regular polygon. (In many similar cases, the reason for a property is captured by such a regular polygon with so many sides so that the involved angles are angles between its sides and/or diagonals and/or angles related to triangles built by vertices and the center.) To have arguments in a simple story, geometric movements of the plane (rotations, translations) are used. We will use numbers for the vertices of such regular polygons, so when the points $0,9$ will appear, this will announce its appearance soon.

We start with the equilateral $\Delta ABC$ with the given point $D$ on the angle bisector from $A$, and angle trisectors from $A,B$, so that the isosceles $\Delta DAB$ has $20^\circ$ angles in $A,B$.
We construct the parallelograms $BD0A$, $AB9D$, with angles of $20^\circ$, $160^\circ$, and $AB=0D=D9=AC=BC$, and $0A=AD=DB=B9$. The lines $AB$ and $0D9$ are parallel. Construct now the $18$-gon
$$\Pi$$
centered in $D$ with $0,9$ as opposite vertices. Its vertices are denoted by $0,1,2,\dots$ using numbers. In order to have "compact" notations, we will use a prime to denote reflection w.r.t. the diameter $0D9$, so $9=9'$, $10=8'$, $11=7'$, and so on till $17=1'$, $0=0'$.
We know the angles of the above parallelograms, so $8,B,D,1'$ are collinear, and so are also $8',D,A,1$. A picture so far, also having later ingrediends:


(This is a good point to try to figure out a possible solution.)

$9D0$ is a diameter and the angles it forms with $9B$ (in the isosceles $\Delta 9BD$) and $92$ in (the circumcircle of) $\Pi$ are both $20^\circ$, so $9B2$ is a line. It makes the angle $40^\circ$ w.r.t. $BD$, a part of the diameter $8BD1'$. We reflect this line w.r.t. this diameter $8BD1'$, and obtain the line $7B4'$, which makes the same angle with $BD$, so it is the line $BC$. This shows $7,B,C,4'$ colinear.
This gives the location of $E$, it is $4'$ since it is on $BC$, and we have $D4'=D0=AB$.
We compute the needed angle. The line $CD$ is perpendicular on the direction $AB\|0D9\|3'6'$, so it bisects $\widehat {3'D6'}$ in two angles of $30^\circ$. Because $\widehat {3'D4'}=20^\circ$ we obtain:
$$\widehat {CDE}=\widehat {CD4'}=30^\circ-20^\circ=10^\circ\ .$$
$\square$

Solution 1:  Apply sine rule to $\triangle BCD, \triangle DCE$
$$ \frac{ \sin 40 ^ \circ } { \sin 110^\circ } = \frac{ DC} { CB} = \frac{ DC } { DE } = \frac{ \sin (30^\circ - x ) } { \sin 150^\circ}.$$
Calculating $ \frac{ \sin 150^\circ \sin 40 ^ \circ } { \sin 110^\circ } = \frac{  \frac{1}{2} \times 2 \sin 20^\circ \cos 20^ \circ } { \cos 20^ \circ } = \sin 20 ^ \circ $, hence $ x = 10 ^ \circ$.

Solution 2: Continuing on from OP's work, applying Trigonometric form of Ceva's theorem on $\triangle DEF$, we want
$$ \frac{ \sin x} {\sin 30^\circ - x }  \times \frac{ \sin (45^\circ + x/2)} { \sin (35^\circ - x/2) }\times \frac{\sin 40^\circ } { \sin 30 ^ \circ} = 1. $$
Note that $ 0 \leq x < 30 ^ \circ$. In this domain, the numerator is positive and increasing in $x$, and the denominator is positive and decreasing in $x$, so there exists a unique solution.
Finally, observe that $ x = 10 ^ \circ$ satisfies the equation, as we have the "well-known identity":
$$ \sin 10^\circ \sin 40^\circ \sin 50^\circ = \frac{\sin 20^\circ}{4} $$
Hence, $ x = 10 ^ \circ$.
Proof of identity: $ \sin 10^\circ \sin 40^\circ \sin 50^\circ  = \frac{\sin 10^\circ \sin 40^\circ \sin 100^\circ} { 2 \cos 50^\circ} = \frac{ \sin 10 ^ \circ \cos 10 ^ \circ } { 2} = \frac{ \sin 20 ^ \circ } { 4}.  $

Is there any synthetic solution?

@DS yes, try to construct a triangle congruent with $CDE$. I succed but after Calvin Lin show me the answer:)

@ale Can you add your solution? Thanks!

Let $F$ be the point on the ray $BD$ beyond $D$ such that $DF=BC$. We have $\angle FDA = 40^\circ = \angle DAC$ and $AD=DB$. By SAS, $\triangle DAF \equiv \triangle BDC \equiv \triangle ADC$. It follows that $ADCF$ is an isosceles trapezoid.
Note that $\angle FCD = 180^\circ - \angle CDA = 180^\circ - 110^\circ = 70^\circ = \angle CDF$. This shows that $CDF$ is an isosceles triangle with $FD=FC$.
Let $G\neq C$ be the point on $BC$ with $FG=FC$. Since $G, C, D$ lie on the circle with center $F$ and radius $FD=FC=FG$, we have $\angle DFG = 2\angle DCF = 60^\circ$. This proves that $DFG$ is an equilateral triangle. Thus $DG = FD = BC$. Thus $G$ coincides with $E$.
To finish, simply observe that $\angle CDG = \frac 12 \angle CFG = \frac 12 \cdot 20^\circ = 10^\circ$.


Best solution by far (+1)

Another trigonometric solution:
Drop a perpendicular from $D$ onto $BC$ and let it have length $h$. Let $BC=DE = a$, $\angle DEB = \theta$. Then
$$\begin{align}
\csc \theta &= \frac ah \\
&= \cot 40^\circ + \cot 30^\circ \\
&= \frac{\cos40^\circ}{\sin40^\circ}+\frac{\cos30^\circ}{\sin30^\circ} \\
&= \frac{\cos40^\circ\sin30^\circ+\cos30^\circ\sin40^\circ}{\sin40^\circ\sin30^\circ} \\
&= \frac{2\sin70^\circ}{\sin40^\circ} \\
&= \frac{2\cos20^\circ}{\sin40^\circ} \\
&= \csc20^\circ
\end{align}$$
Thus, $\boxed{\angle CDE = 10^\circ}$.

Why the downvote?
